# Suma de una Suma

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente código

```
SELECT a.fecha, sum(a.cantidad) as cantidad, b.ClaveGeneral
FROM [dbo].[TB_Almacen] a 
inner join [dbo].[TB_Productos] b on a.id_Producto = b.Id_Producto 
where fecha >'20211107' and fecha < '20211109'    
group by a.fecha, b.clavegeneral
```

Necesito obtener la suma de la columna cantidad la cual debería de ser 12, pero al tener ahí una fecha en mi consulta no se como manejarlo, mi salida es la siguiente, pero quiero que me obtenga un 12

Salida deseada

```
Fecha                      Cantidad          ClaveGeneral
2021-11-07 15:49:39          12           ETNIA3029NG22-27PD
```

Sin embargo la consulta que obtengo es la siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se supone que tu salida deseada en realidad es sólo año, mes y día, sin nada de la hora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecciona solo la fecha del campo `fecha` y agrúpalo de la misma forma:

```
    SELECT convert(date, a.fecha) as fecha, sum(a.cantidad) as cantidad, b.ClaveGeneral
    FROM [dbo].[TB_Almacen] a 
    inner join [dbo].[TB_Productos] b on a.id_Producto = b.Id_Producto 
    where fecha >'20211107' and fecha < '20211109'    
    group by convert(date,a.fecha), b.clavegeneral
```

Answer (score 0):

Si la suma se refiere al día, podrías agrupar por fecha pero formateada, ya que al no tenerla formateada no agrupa al ser diferente, puedes hacer algo:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(fecha, 'MMM-dd-yyyy') AS ffecha, 
    SUM(a.cantidad) AS cantidad, 
    b.ClaveGeneral
FROM 
    [dbo].[TB_Almacen] a  INNER JOIN [dbo].[TB_Productos] b ON a.id_Producto = b.Id_Producto 
WHERE 
    fecha > '20211107' AND fecha < '20211109'    
GROUP BY FORMAT(fecha, 'MMM-dd-yyyy'), b.clavegeneral
```